# Upgrading Rails 2.3.11 to 3.1.3 - trying to replace proxy_owner with proxy_association.owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Working on upgrading an internal gem from Rails 2.3.11 to 3.1.3 - have the following piece of code which models a channel of actions:

```
  has_many :actions, :class_name => 'Streamer::Model::Action', :through => :action_channel_entries, :order => 'actions.id desc' do
    def publish(action)
      proxy_association.owner.publish(action)
    end

    def subscriptions
      proxy_association.owner.subscriptions
    end
  end
```

Instead of a CollectionProxy the self in this has_many is an ActiveRecord::Relation as the error from my unit test demonstrates:

```
undefined local variable or method `proxy_association' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x106d60f68>
from /Users/brett/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@ncsl_r313/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:459:in `method_missing'
from /Users/brett/Projects/ncsl/app/lib/streamer/model/action_channel.rb:11:in `subscriptions'
from (irb):10
```

Right now I'm just looking for suggestions on how to investigate this further and perhaps some understanding of the different uses of CollectionProxy and ActiveRecord::Relation.

Comment: Turns out to be an issue in Rails:  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3890

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
@association.owner
```

Comment: I think that would work if this were a CollectionProxy, but the ActiveRecord::Relation doesn't have any of those methods (or instance variables) - thought I might need to do something like load_target , but that isn't available either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed via this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3890